# How can i generate a file automatically when another file changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, t4, resx

I have an **xml** file (resource.xml) in my **asp.net mvc** project and a **T4** file (resource.tt) to convert that file to **json** in a .js file (resource.js).

The issue is i want to run t4 file automatically when resource.xml file changes or saved.

I know that in asp.net has a **.resx** file that when it changes, a custom tool automatically generate a file,

I want something like that

**Update:**
In my project I have an xml file in **/Resources/Resource.fr.xml** and a t4 file that read the xml file and generate json object in **/Resources/Resource.fr.js** file.
I want to t4 file generate the .js file when xml file saved or changes.

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question you posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997308/how-can-set-the-custom-tool-property-of-an-xml-file-to-a-t4-file/15037150#15037150

Answer (score 2):

I have just answered this sort of question in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243926/run-t4-script-as-custom-tool-for-resx-file/28307797#28307797)

> Check this out: https://github.com/thomaslevesque/AutoRunCustomTool or 
> https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ecb123bf-44bb-4ae3-91ee-a08fc1b9770e
>
>
>
> From the readme:
>
> > After you install the extension, you should see a new Run custom tool on property on each project item. Just edit this property to add the name(s) of the target file(s). That's it!
>
> "target" files are your .tt files

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the FileSystemWatcher class. It monitors changes to a file or even to a folder.

Look at this example:

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run(@"C:\Users\Hanlet\Desktop\Watcher\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug");  
        }
        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public static void Run(string path)
        {

            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path =path;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            watcher.Filter = "*.xml";

            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }

        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.FullPath.IndexOf("resource.xml") > - 1)
                Console.WriteLine("The file was: " + e.ChangeType);
        }
    }
}
```

This monitors and catches everytime the resource.xml file suffers some kind of change (created, deleted or updated). Good luck!

Comment: can you get me more details? how can i implement it in a visual studio project and wach my file?

Comment: thanks, please tell me if how I can run this codes when visual studio builds/file saved?